# Setting an array property from a single ${property} in Spring bean

Tags: java, arrays, spring, properties

I'm using property-based configuration using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

One of my Spring beans requires an array of `String`. Since I can't know the exact size of the array, and I want to avoid to change the Spring beans file (otherwise I wouldn't use properties), is there a way to define something like:

```
property.value={string1,string2}

<property name="theArray" value="${property.value}" />
```

I haven't tried anything so far, I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPEL as this:

```
property.value=string1,string2

<property name="theArray" value="#{'${property.value}'.split(',')}" />
```

Note that I have dropped `{` and `}` from the value for the split to work. If you must have those braces then the SPEL may need to be updated accordingly. I can post that too if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Value and split up your properties by filter

```
profiles.test=1,2,3



     @Value("#{'${profiles.test}'.split(',')}")
     private List<String> propertiesTest;
```